# App Engine: CPU Over Quota on urlfetch()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hey. I'm quite new to App Engine. I created a web-based Twitter app which is now running on App Engine and I'm constantly hitting my CPU Over Quota limits. I did a little profiling and I found out that every request consists of two urlfetch queries, each one of which takes up to 2 CPU seconds. That time is probably spent waiting, all the rest of the code is done in under 200 ms (including work with the Datastore). The Quota is for 6.5 hours per day and every request of mine takes approx. 4 CPU seconds. I ran out of the free quota this morning in only a few hours.

What is the way around this? I can't make Twitter respond to my API calls quicker, and I cannot cache the results, since every request is for a different Twitter profile.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=678

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html seems to indicate that it's not the fetch?  Did check the deadline parameter

Comment: Are you sure the URLFetch is consuming CPU time, and not just wallclock time? Can you post a picture of the appstats screen?

Comment: @Nick, apstats reports CPU time but it doesn't seem to count towards the CPU quota.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Can you post a screenshot of the appstats page?

Answer (score 3):

I would find it confusing that time spent in urlfetch to wait for a remote response is counted towards your CPU quota, given that there is no CPU time spent.

But assuming that's really the problem, [asynchronous requests](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) may be your solution. At a minimum, you can overlap the two urlfetch requests to proceed simultaneously. Perhaps you find other stuff you can do until the response is back.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is that the two requests to the Twitter API are separate HTTP requests one if which is fired during an AJAX call as soon as the first request is finished. Also, you mentioned there's other work I could do during the requests if I fetch them async, problem #2 is that there isn't. All the rest is dune under 200 ms.

Comment: I guess then you need to bite the bullet and pay for more CPU time.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea async requests were possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the design of your application.

Instead of making requests to Twitter from App Engine for every user request:

- Do the request in the user's browser with JavaScript if possible.
- After a urlfetch, store Twitter's response in the datastore, since a call to the datastore is faster on the next request. If you can cache something in memcache, even better.
- Update the stored data regularly with the help of cron jobs and task queue.

Comment: Hmm. Since I'm using two calls: `user_timeline` and `statuses_followers` which both do not require authentication, I guess I can pretty much go with javascript and store the results for search engine crawlers. Seems to be a good idea, thanks!

Comment: I'd favor using the Twitter API directly from the client. It's fairly simple if you are not doing too much server-side crunching.